# Making UI control update once after getting multiple value changes from different sources

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have an array of `GridElement` containing `Value` property and sending `ValueChanged` events. 1000 instances of it are created (for 200x5 grid).

There's an UI Control `public class GridSummary : Label` and its purpose is to show the summed value of all of the 1000 subscribed instances of `GridElement`. *I want to be able to do more complicated calculation on subscribed objects, `Sum()` is just for show.*

There are methods that change the value of all `GridElement` instances, thus firing the `ValueChanged` event 1000 times.

**Objective: make data update both fast and graceful**

The `GridElement` object containing `Value` and `ValueChanged` event:

```
public class GridElement
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Column { get; private set; }
    public int Row { get; private set; }
    private double _value;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { if ( _value != value ) { _value = value; if ( ValueChanged != null ) ValueChanged( this, EventArgs.Empty ); } }
    }

    public GridElement( string name, int column, int row )
    {
        Name = name;
        Column = column;
        Row = row;
    }

    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
}
```

My current solutions (`GridSummary` implementations):

## 1. Refresh on each call

```
public class GridSummary : Label
{
    List<GridElement> _gridElements;

    public GridSummary() : base()
    {
        _gridElements = new List<GridElement>();
    }

    public void Subscribe( GridElement gridElement )
    {
        if ( gridElement != null )
        {
            _gridElements.Add( gridElement );
            gridElement.ValueChanged += GridElement_ValueChanged;
            GridElement_ValueChanged( gridElement, EventArgs.Empty );
        }
    }

    private void GridElement_ValueChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        double value = _gridElements.Sum( x => x.Value );
        Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

It's unbearably slow because this label is refreshed 1000 times. It could be sped up by setting `AutoSize` to `false`, or doing fancy operations on `Suspend/ResumeLayout` (or even go deeper to WinAPI).

## 2. Using `Application.Idle` to update on idle state

```
public class GridSummary : Label
{
    List<GridElement> _gridElements;

    public GridSummary() : base()
    {
        _gridElements = new List<GridElement>();
        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
    }

    private bool _update = false;
    private void Application_Idle( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( _update )
        {
            _update = false;
            double value = _gridElements.Sum( x => x.Value );
            Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe( GridElement gridElement )
    {
        if ( gridElement != null )
        {
            _gridElements.Add( gridElement );
            gridElement.ValueChanged += GridElement_ValueChanged;
            GridElement_ValueChanged( gridElement, EventArgs.Empty );
        }
    }

    private void GridElement_ValueChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        _update = true;
    }
}
```

This one is much faster, because UI control is refreshed only once. But it uses `Application.Idle` event which I'm not sure is a nice way of dealing with UI elements.

Some points concerning me about using the #2 method:

- is subscribing to `Application.Idle` in the constructor method a good idea, or should it be handled differently (Layout/Runtime mode)?
- should I unsubscribe the `Application.Idle` event? This control isn't disposed until the very end of the application
- should it be actually done completely different, maybe using `Invalidate`/`Refresh`/`Update`/`Paint` methods/overrides/callbacks?

Comment: instead of assigning the text property...assign a string...have a separate loop that updates text every so amount of milliseconds...so nothing is trying to update the GUI thousands of times a second...kinda like would be done in a video game loop

Comment: Currently `Application.Idle` makes text update only once so theoretically it's less intensive than setting up timers. I was hoping for an elegant way of dealing with updates, setting up `timer.Tick` and using buffers for strings feels overly complicated and not reliable.

Comment: *Because `Application.Idle` is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.* Override `Dispose` method of your control and unsubscribe [`Application.Idle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).